# Position a div next to two images that are displayed inline in one containing div

Tags: css, image, html, position, inline

Consider the following [site](http://www.penandpixelmedia.com/Best_Technique).

I am trying to position a div that is approx 300px wide by about 400px high next to the picture of the woman. I have tried to display the div as inline but to no avail. I tried to float left but once again no luck. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can position it next to the image, by using the following CSS:

```
.emailForm {
    width: 260px; /* anything above 260px will fall over to the next line */
    /*float: right;*/ /* remove float */
    display: inline-block; /* inline-block since you want specific width and height */
    height: 434px;
    border: 1px solid black;
}
```

*NOTE:* Pretty sure you are using it, but in case you aren't, do use Firebug or Chrome dev tools for making such tasks a breeze.

Comment: Thanks, that seemed to solve it. I tried using inline-block but nothing happened, i guess it was because the width was just too much. I adjusted the dimensions of the elements a bit and everything works.

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
 <div id="wrap">
 <div id="nextTo"></div>
 <img id="woman" src="#" width="600px" height="400px" />
 </div>
```

CSS

```
 #wrap {width: 1000px; margin: 0 auto;}
 #nextTo {float: right; max-height: 400px;}
```

This will ensure that your image is fixed width. If you have a wrapper div that is 1000px wide for example, the `#nextTo` div will be the remainder of what the image takes up (in my example 400px).

Adding the `max-height` attribute to the `#nextTo` div ensures that the div will not fall below the image, but not sure if this is what you are after.